# Trying to create new Laravel project this error came up

Tags: php, laravel

This is my first laravel project and this error appears I can't figure out the solution and I searched for a solution in stack over flow and tried the solutions I found but it doesn't work.
`composer create-project laravel/laravel newProject4`

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
> packages.
>
> Problem 1
> - laravel/framework[v8.54.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require league/flysystem ^1.1 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[1.1.0, ...,
> 1.x-dev].
> - league/flysystem[1.1.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo
> extension.
> - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.54 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.54.0, ..., 8.x-dev].
>
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\php\php.ini You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

*Edit*
When I wrote php --ini in the command this is what I got

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\php\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Comment: Can you post the entire composer output please?

Comment: just remove the ; inside the php.ini file Locate the line:

;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
Remove the starting comment:

extension=php_fileinfo.dll

Comment: I open the php.ini file and I didn't found and semicolon before the extension

Comment: which php version are you using? if you are using windows you can write in comand line php -v now if you are using linux you can just write php -v

Comment: extension=fileinfo

Comment: please go to command line run it as administrator and write `php --ini` and add the output to your question.

Comment: are  you using windows? or linux?

Comment: I am using windows, php version PHP 8.0.9.

Comment: where are you trying to install laravel project? , in which directory?, you see it seems that you are not using a server environment like XAMPP , please share details about what are you trying to do exactly i will help you. One more question do you have XAMPP?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found the answer,
the problem was that I was removing ; before extension = fileinfo from php.ini inside PHP folder in xampp folder "c:/xampp/php/"
but I didn't remove it from "c:/php/php.ini".

Comment: This worked! I had to open up both files and boom!

Comment: This guy is a SAVIOR ! I was breaking my head why it's not working.. 
I also forgot to remove the `;` from the `;extension=fileinfo` from my path `C:\php-8.2.11\php.ini`

I was only removing it from the xampp path.. 
`C:\xampp\Folder Xampp\php\php.ini`

Answer (score 28):

You need to uncomment the extension `extension = fileinfo` in the `php.ini` file from the source folder. Then delete `projectx` dir. Finally, re-run `laravel new projectx` as per your screenshot.

If you have already uncomment `extension = fileinfo` in `php.ini` and it doesn't work. You might need to grant administrator permissions to be able to execute the changes:

To grant these permissions you have to do the following: Note: This for windows 10.

1. It is located in the file to grant the permission `c:/xampp/php/php.ini`. And for your case its - `C:\MAMP\bin\php\php7.4.1\php.ini`
2. Right click on the file and click on properties.
3. Security.
4. Click on the Edit button.
5. Click on each of the group or user names and at the bottom where it says Permissions for authenticated users, and then check full control.

In this way permission is granted and now if the changes to the file are saved.

Comment: I did all of the previous but it doesn't work!!

Comment: thank you so much, it worked . I removed the `;` before  `extension=fileinfo` ,saved the php.ini file and the error never returned .

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why the laravel documentation doesn't mention it. Must be very hard to keep up-to-date documentation.

Answer (score 5):

uncomment the extension "extension = fileinfo" in the php.ini

```
;extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
```

Answer (score -1):

i found the problem and it seems very simple. the error I received was because extension=fileinfo is not active, if it is php.delete the semicolon ';' in the ';extension=fileinfo' line in the ini file and restart the server. i hope this will be the solution :)

Answer (score -1):

In my case the solution was that I added the php environment variable from xammp 'C:\xampp\php', instead of 'C:\Users\ana\Downloads\Compressed\php'
and remove the semicolon befor the 'extension=fileinfo' from 'C:\xampp\php.ini' file