# Installing Laravel breeze

Tags: laravel, composer-php, breeze

```
PS D:\Student-Dashboard> composer require laravel/breeze --dev
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/breeze
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.7.1] require league/flysystem ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.14.0].
    - league/flysystem[3.8.0, ..., 3.14.0] require league/mime-type-detection ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.11.0].
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.0.0, ..., 1.3.0] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.4) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - league/mime-type-detection[1.4.0, ..., 1.11.0] require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^10.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.0.0, ..., v10.7.1].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\php-8.2.4-Win32-vs16-x64\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-fileinfo` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/breeze:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/breeze:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I am try to install laravel/breeze. but this error comes.

Comment: "_require ext-fileinfo * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's fileinfo extension._" Have you tried this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to create new Laravel project this error came up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69325402/trying-to-create-new-laravel-project-this-error-came-up)

Comment: You forgot to share your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score -1):

Turn on fileinfo PHP Extension from php.ini file.

Step 1: Goto your php.ini file
Step 2: Open that File with your code editor.
Step 3: Search for fileinfo by pressing ctrl+f.
Step 4: remove ";" from the fileinfo prefix.
Step 5: Save your file.

Then  run your command.

Comment: Please do not duplicate existing answers. Enabling any extension is already part of tons of other answers on StackOverflow